# Getting value using a key from a dictionary acts differently in 2 methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary of `key:value` pair in this format:

```py
py_dict = {
    "value": {
        "Timestamp(" "2020-04-05 02:48:00" ")": 699.0,
        "Timestamp(" "2020-06-26 07:36:00" ")": "nan",
        "Timestamp(" "2020-06-26 08:40:00" ")": 699.0,
     }
}
```

I am able to grab the key I need (latest timestamp) using `datetime.strptime()`

```py
timestamps = {
    datetime.strptime(key.strip('Timestamp("').strip('")'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"): value
    for key, value in py_dict["value"].items()
    if value != "nan"
}

# Find the maximum timestamp
latest_timestamp = max(timestamps)

# latest_timestamp returns <class 'datetime.datetime'> 2020-06-26 08:40:00
```

I convert the datetime object back to a string and format it to how the `py_dict["value"]` keys are structured

```py
formatted_latest_timestamp_key = (
    'Timestamp(" "' + latest_timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + '" ")'
)

# returns <class 'str'> Timestamp(" "2020-06-26 08:40:00" ")
```

When I run the `dict.get()` method against the `formatted_latest_timestamp_key` I get `none`

```py
latest_price = py_dict["value"].get(f'"{formatted_latest_timestamp_key}"')

# returns none
```

But if I run `py_dict["value"].get()` on the hardcoded key , I get the respective price.

My Python version:

```py
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.12
```

Comment: You don’t need the `f'"…"'` around your already formatted string…!?

Comment: The `" "` is also nonsense. You just need `'Timestamp(' + latest_timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ')'`. Print your existing dict/key to see what it actually looks like.

Comment: @deceze, yeah. I see my "nonsense" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confused about the actual key values in this subdictionary:

```
py_dict = {
    "value": {
        "Timestamp(" "2020-04-05 02:48:00" ")": 699.0,
        "Timestamp(" "2020-06-26 07:36:00" ")": "nan",
        "Timestamp(" "2020-06-26 08:40:00" ")": 699.0,
     }
}
```

Looking at just the first key:

```
"Timestamp(" "2020-04-05 02:48:00" ")"
```

It is composed of three separate adjacent string literals:

```
Timestamp(
2020-04-05 02:48:00
)
```

When Python sees multiple adjacent string literals, they are joined together automatically.  So the actual string key value is this:

```
Timestamp(2020-04-05 02:48:00)
```

It contains no double-quote characters, and only one space.

Here is a simplified example of this behavior:

```
>>> a = "hello" "there"
>>> print(a)
hellothere
>>>
```